# Can anyone tell me why my calculateCoin function doesnt show up?

Tags: java

Can anyone help me why the calculateCoin function doesn't show up? Basically what it does is, it calculates the coin, that was generated randomly in the drawMap function within 20% chance.

What I did and not sure doing right is, I called the calculateCoin function IN the drawMap function, and then I call the drawMap in the main.

[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();

    System.out.println(main.drawMap());
}

public int[][] drawMap(){
    int[][] map = new int[5][5];
    char coin = 'o';

    for(int i =0; i<map.length; i++){
        for(int j =0; j<map[i].length; j++){
            map[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            if(map[i][j]<2){
                System.out.print(coin+ " ");
            }
            else
            System.out.print("*"+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    calculateCoin(map, coin);
    System.out.println("");

    return map;
}

public int calculateCoin(int[][] map, char coin){
    int result = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<map.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<map[i].length; j++){
            if(map[i][j] == coin){
                result++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "show up" but you call `calculateCoin` and you discard the result (i.e. you don't assign the return value to any variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is actually being called but the value that you return from it is not stored in any variable. If you want something to happen after printing the map, store the result of the call in a variable and then print it.

```
int calculatedCoin = calculateCoin(map, coin);
System.out.println("Calculated coin: " + calculatedCoin)
```

Comment: ahh right, i simply didnt print whats in the function, right? why do i keep missing that part...
so what RETURN means in an int function, is to just simply return it to whoever calls the function, but actually doesnt automatically print it out?

Answer (score 0):

try this , but basically you declare a type of a class not a method.

```
public class dave {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    dave main = new dave();
    System.out.println(dave.drawMap());
}

public static int[][] drawMap() {
    int[][] map = new int[5][5];
    char coin = 'o';

    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            map[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            if (map[i][j] < 2) {
                System.out.print(coin + " ");
            } else
                System.out.print("*" + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    calculateCoin(map, coin);
    System.out.println("");

    return map;
}

public static int calculateCoin(int[][] map, char coin) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            if (map[i][j] == coin) {
                result++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: I genuinely dont understand, what do you mean i declare a type of a class instead of a method? which part?